# Flexible making widgets overflow in Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, flutter-web

I am building a Flutter web-app, where I have a menu interface with 4 Iconbuttons and 1 MaterialButton that is the users profile, like this:[image]
I am using Flexible to make sure there is no overflow, but if I minimise the window, the Iconbuttons overflow, like this:
[image]
Is there any way to prevent this from happening? This is my code:

```
child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            Flexible(
              flex: 2,
              child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.chat_bubble_outline_rounded,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  onPressed: null),
            ),
            Flexible(
              flex: 2,
              child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.settings_outlined,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  onPressed: null),
            ),
            Flexible(
              flex: 2,
              child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    FontAwesomeIcons.wallet,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  onPressed: null),
            ),
            Flexible(
              flex: 2,
              child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.notifications_outlined,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  onPressed: null),
            ),
            MaterialButton(
              shape: CircleBorder(),
              onPressed: () {
                print('click');
              },
              child: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(user.photoURL.toString()),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want to achieve?

[image]

You could achieve this with a `SingleChildScrollView`.

I combined the `SingleChildScrollView` with a `ConstrainedBox` to allow the spread of the icons if the screen is larger than needed.

```
LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: constraints.maxWidth),
        child: Row(...),
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

### Full source code for easy copy-paste

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(width: 800, child: MyBar()),
            const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
            Container(width: 400, child: MyBar()),
            const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
            Container(width: 200, child: MyBar()),
            const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
            Container(
              width: 100,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(child: MyBar()),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyBar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
      color: Colors.amber.shade300,
      child: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                minWidth: constraints.maxWidth,
              ),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.chat_bubble_outline_rounded,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      onPressed: null),
                  IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.settings_outlined,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      onPressed: null),
                  IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        FontAwesomeIcons.wallet,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      onPressed: null),
                  IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.notifications_outlined,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      onPressed: null),
                  MaterialButton(
                    shape: CircleBorder(),
                    onPressed: () {
                      print('click');
                    },
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      child: Text('X'),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Flexible will solve the problem here. Instead of this I have two options for you.

**1) Replace Row with ListView (also provide scrollDirection as horizontal).**

This will prevent the overflow and the list will be scrollable when the screen will be resized to a smaller width. I will prefer doing this.

**2) Scale all the buttons with respect to the screen width.**
This will provide you a responsive layout as the buttons will resize as the screen width changes. But you need to make sure that they don't get so small that user will find it difficult to press them.